How can set dynamically id to tag and use it in the same tag
I want to create an angular component by using mat-button-toggle-group and need to render mat-button-toggle with ngFor.
For example I set #yesterday in mat-button-toggle and use it in ngClass
<mat-button-toggle-group class="d-flex align-items-center" #group="matButtonToggleGroup" multiple (change)="toggleChange($event)">
    <mat-button-toggle value="yesterday" #yesterday [ngClass]="{'accent': yesterday.checked}">
        <span>{{ 'GENERAL_KEYS.FILTER_PARAMS.YESTERDAY' | translate }}</span>
    </mat-button-toggle>
    <mat-button-toggle value="today" #today [ngClass]="{'accent': today.checked}" checked>
        <span>{{ 'GENERAL_KEYS.FILTER_PARAMS.TODAY' | translate }}</span>
    </mat-button-toggle>
    <mat-button-toggle value="tomorrow" #tomorrow [ngClass]="{'accent': tomorrow.checked}">
        <span>{{ 'GENERAL_KEYS.FILTER_PARAMS.TOMORROW' | translate }}</span>
    </mat-button-toggle>
</mat-button-toggle-group>


How can I set id to tag and use it again?

You need to access the export with matButtonToggle as mentioned in the docs
<mat-button-toggle-group name="fontStyle" aria-label="Font Style">
  <mat-button-toggle
    *ngFor="let item of toggleProps"
    [value]="item.value"
    #buttonToggle="matButtonToggle"
    [ngClass]="{'accent': buttonToggle.checked}"
    >{{item.label}}</mat-button-toggle
  >
</mat-button-toggle-group>

TS:
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MatButtonToggleModule } from '@angular/material/button-toggle';

/**
 * @title Basic button-toggles
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'button-toggle-overview-example',
  templateUrl: 'button-toggle-overview-example.html',
  standalone: true,
  styles: [
    `
  ::ng-deep .accent {
    background-color: red !important;
  }
  `,
  ],
  imports: [MatButtonToggleModule, CommonModule],
})
export class ButtonToggleOverviewExample {
  toggleProps: any = [
    { value: 'bold', label: 'Bold' },
    { value: 'italic', label: 'Italic' },
    { value: 'underline', label: 'Underline' },
  ];
}

Stackblitz Demo
